# Can we add javascript function in lightning component layout?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can we add javascript function in lightning component layout ?

Comment: Why you need to write script in component layout when you have controller bind with it ? Write any script inside controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not include javascript function in lightning component layout .You can provide link of external script using-

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```